# BinarySearchTree Insert Method not working

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-search-tree

I recently started coding, so don't be to harsh on me. I'm trying to implement an insert method in a Binary Search Tree. Every time I tree to insert something other than a root, the web console crashes. Here is the code:

```js
insert(val) {
    let node = new Node (val)
    if (this.root === null) {
        this.root = node
    }
    else {
        let loop = this.root;
        while (loop) {
            if (node.val < loop.val) {
                if (loop.left === null) {
                    loop.left = node;
                }
                if (loop.left === node) {
                    break;
                }
                if (loop.left !== null) {
                    loop = loop.left;
                }
            }
            else if (node.val > loop.val) {
                if (loop.right === null) {
                    loop.right = node
                }
                if (loop.right === node) {
                    break;
                }
                if (loop.right !== null) {
                    loop = loop.right;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Its probably because of the loop, but I do have a break condition that should stop it at the right time. The logic makes perfect sense in my mind, perhaps there is something I'm missing

Comment: There is no problem with your `insert` method (although it could be written in a more elegant way). The problem must be elsewhere. Please add the code that is necessary to actually run the code and see the problem occur.